# How to bump the version of a package available in another user's PPA?

Tags: package-management, ppa, cmake

When looking for a recent version of CMake 3.2 for Ubuntu 15.04 I came across [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~george-edison55/+archive/ubuntu/cmake-3.x). However, instead of CMake 3.2.1 I'd like to use version 3.2.3. How can I easily build upon the existing work done for that PPA to achieve that? I imagine some workflow like

1. copy the packages from the PPA to my own newly created PPA
2. somehow download the existing build recipes for version 3.2.1 (Using `dget`?)
3. increase the version string in some file, adjust the changelog etc.
4. push the build recipes back to Launchpad to see if it builds

So far I've only been able to find instructions on how to create new PPAs / packages from upstream sources (involving Bazaar branches and what not), but no easy instructions how to build upon existing PPA packages (preferably without involving Bazaar).

Note that I have no experience whatsoever with building / publishing PPAs, and that I'm starting from scratch.

Comment: How does that answer help me with creating my own PPA and packages based on another PPA's packages?

Comment: Of course not. But I was assuming that there must be some sort for build recipe as part of the existing PPA packages that says something like "download cmake version X from server Y and apply patches Z". And I'd simply like to make X say 3.2.3 instead of 3.2.1 so the proper sources get downloaded.

Comment: Ask @NathanOsman in the chat. =)

Comment: I already wrote him a mail, but I'd not like to bother other PPA maintainers too much, but instead to the work myself if possible.

Comment: Ask him here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Download cmake 3.2.3 from [here](http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.2/cmake-3.2.3.tar.gz).
2. Extract the tarball, the path should be `cmake-3.2.3`.
3. Now rename the tarball:

   ```
   mv cmake-3.2.3.tar.gz cmake_3.2.3.orig.tar.gz
   ```
4. Download the [packaging](https://launchpad.net/~george-edison55/+archive/ubuntu/cmake-3.x/+files/cmake_3.2.1-1ppa3%7Evivid1.debian.tar.xz) part from the ppa for 15.04.
5. Extract `cmake_3.2.1-1ppa3~vivid1.debian.tar.xz` into `cmake-3.2.3`

   ```
   cmake-3.2.3
     ├── debian
     │   ├── changelog
     ...
   ```
6. Update the debian/changelog as follow (just change the signature):

   ```
   cmake (3.2.3-1ppa1~vivid1) vivid; urgency=medium

     * New upstream release.

    -- Sylvain Pineau <sylvain.pineau@canonical.com>  Tue, 30 Jun 2015 11:24:26 +0200

   cmake (3.2.1-1ppa3~vivid1) vivid; urgency=medium

     * Fix path to icons in cmake-qt-gui.

    -- Nathan Osman <nathan@quickmediasolutions.com>  Mon, 30 Mar 2015 17:59:20 -0700
   ```
7. Install the build dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep cmake
   sudo apt-get install liblzma-dev
   ```
8. Build a new source package for `cmake` with:

   ```
   cd cmake-3.2.3
   dpkg-buildpackage -S
   ```
9. Upload the source package to your ppa with:

   ```
   cd ..
   dput ppa:<user_name>/<ppa_name> cmake_3.2.3-1ppa1~vivid1_source.changes
   ```
10. Monitor the build progress in your ppa homepage

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works. I just had to do `apt-get build-dep cmake` before to install the build dependencies. Is there any value in using `dch` here instead of editing the `changelog` manually?

Comment: @sschuberth Sorry for the missing step (I did it as well but forgot to paste it). If you're familiar with the `dch` syntax that's even better. Manual edits are too error-prone so it's a good reason to rely on `dch`.

Comment: Thanks again. Even if it probably is quite specific to my use-case I've wrapped the steps in a [script](https://github.com/sschuberth/dev-scripts/blob/master/ubuntu/ppa-bump-cmake.sh), maybe that's useful to someone.